# Detect if script is already running in bash script, and only restart if not

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that will check if a script is already running, and not run it on cron if its still going from the last run. I found another post on here where they suggested using:

```
echo `pgrep -f $0` . "!=" . "$$";
if [[ `pgrep -f $0` != "$$" ]];
```

While this seems to work when I run it manually in SSH, it gives weird results when run via cron:

> 14767 14770 . != . 14770

Is this because there are 2 processes running with 2 different `pid`s?

I have come up with this as an alternative:

```
if [ -n "$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep 'run.sh' | wc -l)" > 2 ];
then
    echo "already running"
else
  # do some stuff here
fi
```

Running the command on its own seems to work as expected:

```
# ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep 'run.sh' | wc -l)
2
```

But when in the code, it always shows "already running" , even though my condition is not met:

```
bash run.sh
2
already running
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the variable as an int?

UPDATE: As suggested, I am trying `flock`:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :

#... rest of code here
```

But I get:

> flock: failed to execute run.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your code like that but it will be complex and errorprone. Better to use [file-locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking). The `flock` command exists for this. Its man-page provides various examples you can cut and paste, including:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :

# ... rest of code ...
```

> This is useful boilerplate code for shell scripts.   Put  it  at
> the top of the shell script you want to lock and it'll automatically
> lock itself on the first run.  If the env var $FLOCKER  is
> not  set  to  the  shell  script that is being run, then execute
> flock and grab an exclusive non-blocking lock (using the  script
> itself as the lock file) before re-execing itself with the right
> arguments.  It also sets the FLOCKER env var to the right  value
> so it doesn't run again.

`man flock` for details.

Comment: Oh now thats cool! I got this though when running: `flock: failed to execute run.sh: No such file or directory ` (updated opening post to show what I have now)

Comment: @AndrewNewby you shouldn't be using relative pathnames in cron. Use the full path. Or work out the full path (eg. `me=$(realpath "$0")`) and use that instead of `$0`

Comment: ahhh ok makes sense. So I changed to `me=$(realpath "$0")
[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$me" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$me" flock -en "$me" "$me" "$@" || :`, but I now get: `flock: failed to execute /home/full/path/run.sh: Permission denied`. I thought maybe it weas a CHMOD issue on the run.sh script or the dir its in, but that doens't seem to help

Comment: Ah ok - so it was a combo of a "chmod" issue (666 wasn't enough), and also the fact it was owned by a user, but I was running as root. All running fine now - thanks !

Comment: Very bad idea to run a user-owned script as root! Run it as the user.

Comment: I was logged in as root (sysadmin) and testing it from there. I sudo'ed into the user after, but it doesn't run as root on crontab